# Lag per rows of a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, lag, shift

I want to construct a matrix which looks like this:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16]
[1,]    1    0    0   -1    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
[2,]    0    0    0    1    0    0   -1    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    -1     0     0     0     0     0     0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     1     0     0    -1     0     0     0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     1     0     0    -1
```

The way I was thinking about, kind of not nice though, is to create a vector that contains a pattern that will repeat up to fill, *by row*, the  matrix

```
pattern <- c(1,rep(0,2),-1,rep(0,15)) #creating the pattern 
matrix(rep(pattern, 5), 5, 16, byrow = TRUE) #filling a matrix per row with repetitions of the pattern
#Returns:
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16]
[1,]    1    0    0   -1    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
[2,]    0    0    0    1    0    0   -1    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    -1     0     0     0     0     0     0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     1     0     0    -1     0     0     0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     1     0     0    -1
Warning message:
In matrix(rep(pattern, 5), 5, 16, byrow = TRUE) :
  data length [95] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of columns [16]
```

Which gives me what I want but of course with a warning cause I am not using all the elements of the resulted pattern repetition.

Another way I was thinking was, using the `kronecker` product and have something like:

```
kronecker(diag(5),t(c(1,rep(0,2),-1)))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20]
[1,]    1    0    0   -1    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0   -1    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1     0     0    -1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     1     0     0    -1     0     0     0     0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0    -1
```

And then shift/lag to the left each row (starting at the second row) according till obtain the result I am looking for. Is there any way to this shift without using `lag`? Or any suggestion/alternative way of solving? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

**1) set 1d elements**

```
m1 <- matrix(0, 5, 16)
m1[seq(1, length(m1), 16)] <- 1
m1[seq(16, length(m1), 16)] <- -1
```

**2) set 2d elements**

```
m2 <- matrix(0, 5, 16)
m2[cbind(1:5, seq(from = 1, length = 5, by = 16 %/% 5))] <- 1
m2[cbind(1:5, seq(to = 16, length = 5, by = 16 %/% 5))] <- -1
```

**3) set from diag**

```
len <- 5 * 16
d <- c(diag(16 - 1))
m3 <- matrix(head(d, len) - tail(d, len), ncol = 16)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using `for` loop but I think something simpler and faster should be possible -

```
m <- matrix(0, nrow = 5, ncol = 16)

colnum <- seq(1, by = 3, length.out = nrow(m))

for(i in 1:nrow(m)) {
  m[i, colnum[i]:(colnum[i]+3)] <- c(1, 0, 0, -1)
}

m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16]
[1,]    1    0    0   -1    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
[2,]    0    0    0    1    0    0   -1    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    -1     0     0     0     0     0     0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     1     0     0    -1     0     0     0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     1     0     0    -1
```